# Stopping of spinner with javaScript - SpinJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I can start spinner, but dont know how to stop it. Pls help:

```js
//On button click load spinner and go to another page
$("#btn1").click(function () {  
//Loads Spinner
$("#loading").fadeIn();
var opts = {
    lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 7, // The length of each line
    width: 4, // The line thickness
    radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
    color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
    speed: 1, // Rounds per second
    trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
    hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
};
var trget = document.getElementById('loading');
var spnr = new Spinner(opts).spin(trget);
});

 $("#btn2").click(function () {      
    //Write code to stop spinner

});
```

```html
<button  id="btn1">Start</button>
<button id="btn2">Stop</button>

<div id="loading">
<div id="loadingcont">
    <p id="loadingspinr">
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2/spin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Refernces:**

> http://spin.js.org/
>   [Stop Spinner.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958032/stop-spinner-js)

Comment: What is mean by stopping the spinner. Whether you want to hide it or just stop it's spinning.

Comment: Anything, but user must not see it. It should be vanished on 2nd button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code.

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {      
    //Write code to stop spinner
    $('#loading').fadeOut();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just destroy it, for instance - it will disappear

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {      
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML='';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(trget).data('spinner', spnr);
$('loading').data('spinner').stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//On button click load spinner and go to another page
$("#btn1").click(function () {  
//Loads Spinner
$("#loading").fadeIn();
var opts = {
    lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 7, // The length of each line
    width: 4, // The line thickness
    radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
    color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
    speed: 1, // Rounds per second
    trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
    hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
};
var trget = document.getElementById('loading');
var spnr = new Spinner(opts).spin(trget);
});

 $("#btn2").click(function () {      
    //Write code to stop spinner
    $('#loading').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<button  id="btn1">Start</button>
<button id="btn2">Stop</button>

<div id="loading">
<div id="loadingcont">
    <p id="loadingspinr">
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2/spin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the `var spnr` for accessible both the functions,

```
spnr = new Spinner(opts).spin(trget);


----------

 $("#btn2").click(function () {      
    //Write code to stop spinner
    spnr.stop();
});
```